# When building a DLL which will be loaded using LoadLibrary, do I need to link with the dependent binaries or is including the headers enough?

Tags: c, windows, dll

I'm building a plugin (extension module) system for a language interpreter I'm writing in C.

During runtime, the program uses `LoadLibrary` in order to load a specified DLL file. This seems to work, with basic DLLs which don't depend on functions defined in the main program.

However, I'm trying to build a plugin DLL which does depend on functions which are defined in the main program binary.

To do so, I defined a `interface.h` header in the main code base, for these plugins to include and use. It defines the headers for the functions they might require. The plugin does `#include <interface.h>` in its header.

I compile the plugin DLL like so:

```
gcc myplugin.c -shared -Wl,--subsystem,windows -D MYPLUGIN_EXPORTS -o myplugin.dll -I..\main_program_headers
```

I then get the following kind of errors:

```
undefined reference to 'some function name'
```

1. Does this mean I have to compile the plugins with dynamic linking to the actual binaries they depend on in the main program?
2. If so, does this mean I need to keep the individual `.o` files of the main program around, even after linking them to the result `.exe`? Can GCC link directly against the `.o` files?
3. Anyway, I really hoped `LoadLibrary` takes care of fixing the function references on load during runtime. Doesn't it?

**Update:**

As @tenfour kindly answered, a DLL must follow normal linking rules and function references need to be resolved at build time. He / she suggested a system where the host program passes into the plugin pointers for the needed function.

This approach will indeed work, but I would still like to know:

What kind of build process is necessary to allow the plugin to call functions from the main app directly, without any special system at runtime (except for `LoadLibrary`).

I would like to say that my main source of influence here is the extension system for the CPython interpreter. It seems to me judging by [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) that a CPython extension doesn't receive function pointers from the host interpreter, and is still able to directly call `Py_*` functions from it.

Any idea how such a thing can be done? How can the plugin DLL be built to support this? What and how do I need to link against?

Comment: Think of a DLL as a program without the runtime-defined entrypoint (in standard C that would be `main`, for Windows apps a WinMain, etc). The rest of the linkage rules still apply, just as they would for a stand-alone program. Your DLL's dependencies must be fulfilled. Only a static library can get away with not providing implementation; it expects the program/dll linking with the static library to provide whatever is missing when building the final PE image(s). Static libs are literally nothing more than a collection of object files; DLLs are *not*. Perhaps you didn't export your functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post `interface.h`, I can only guess that you are forward-declaring functions there, for example:

```
int some_func();
```

If the plugin code tries to invoke this method, it will compile, but the linker has no reference to it. The body of that function only exists in your host application.

Instead, if you want to dynamically link, using `LoadLibrary`, you need to use function pointers, e.g.:

```
typedef int (*some_func_ptr)(); // declare the fn pointer type
...
some_func_ptr some_func = x; // assign it after the host passes you x
...
some_func(); // now you can call it without linker issues.
```

And viola you have used dynamic linking to create a plugin system. Of course the design of your interface will force this to be more complex but that's mostly just labor once you understand the concept.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed in `interface.h` I'm forward declaring functions (more precisely including other `.h` files from the main code base which do).
What if I want the plugins to be able to call a few dozen functions from the main app directly. How is this normally acheived?

Comment: To elaborate, this is an extension system for a programming language interpreter, inspired by the CPython extension system. And so I'd like extensions to be able to invoke a range of functions in the main interpreter (such as function to create objects, etc).

Comment: After your last edit, elaborating further if I may: your proposed technique is interesting and will work. However, I would prefer to understand how it would be possible for the plugin to invoke directly functions from the main app without the surrounding system you proposed. What kind of build process would be needed?

Comment: If you want pure C, then it's done as I explained. Many devs prefer to use C++ where you can define base classes (imagine `IPluginHost` with a dozen member functions), and the host just passes the plugin a single pointer to an object that implements `IPluginHost`. But really the concept is the same, just less labor-intensive syntax

Comment: I guess I'm referring to the CPython interpreter as my main source of influence.  In its documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) it seems that the extension module simply calls CPython functions directly. Any idea how this can be done?